# Relative (co)homology of closed submanifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a closed orientable manifold of dimension $n$ and $A$ a closed submanifold. I obtained these equivalences on relative homology and cohomology groups (with coefficients in arbitrary ring):

$$\mathrm{H}_*(M,A) \cong \mathrm{H}^\mathrm{BM}_*(M-A) \cong \mathrm{H}^{n-*}(M-A),\\
\mathrm{H}^*(M,A) \cong \mathrm{H}^*_c(M-A) \cong \mathrm{H}_{n-*}(M-A).$$

(Note that the first isomorphism on the second line is obtained by the fact that A is a deformation retract of small neighborhoods, and is not simply "by definition".)

I am not confident on my proof and didn't found a reference. So are these relations always true?

Thanks for your answers and reference suggestions!

Comment: Yes, those relations are true. It will helps if either you give your proofs or at least the definitions you are using in order to give you some references. In any case, the last isomorphism of each line is Poincaré duality and the first, either a definition, or follows from some long exact sequence and the five lemma as soon as you have a map between the two.

Comment: @user113969 I have a little knowledge of Borel-Moore homology and saw its definition at wikipedia. Anyway I didn't found a good reference for the exact definition of BM-homology (at least at standard books) and these isomorphisms. It's very useful if you give a reference which covers these material.

Comment: I recommend Iversen, Cohomology of sheaves. All of the four theories (homology, BM-homology, cohomology, cohomology with support) is developed using the point of view of sheaves.

Comment: @user113969 Thank you very much!